# Specific classes using CSS modules not working in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I can't get CSS modules to work in Js - the plain global CSS module file is working, and so are non-specific classes like body are working, however I can't get classes.className to work for example.
I'd be glad of some help/ closure.
Thanks,

Edit: I don't have an error upon compiling
Edit 2: In Dev Tools no classes are shown unless I declare them statically like "className"

```
import React from "react";
import '.././Index.module.css';
import classes from "./CardLrg.module.css"


function CardLrg(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={classes.cardLrg}>
            <div className={classes.cardLrgHead}>
                <div className={classes.cardLrgDiscount}>{props.discount}</div>
                <img src="../../public/plus-square.svg" alt="Add to basket"/>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.cardLrgMainContent}>{props.sku}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default CardLrg
```

```
.cardLrg {
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px #000000;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(classes)`?

Comment: @DaishoArch, outputting classes return an empty object

Comment: If it returns an empty object, eg `classes.cardLrg` will be `undefined`, makes sense why it's not working then?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: The syntax looks right.The path for the css module need to be in relation to the file using it.  So if you have 
Parent -> css -> CardLrg.module.css  
&
Parent -> component -> card.tsx
(so css folder and component folder are siblings)
It would need to be: import classes from "../css/CardLrg.module.css"

Comment: Also if you aren't using index i'd comment that out. I don't think(not confident about that) you can do .././ it would be ../Index.module.css'

Another debugging thing, if you look at your source do you see any of your class from your module?(if not then definitely double check the path)

Comment: @Ikura my path is 100% working; as I mentioned non-specific selectors, or hard-coded class names eg className=“class” work from that file without being imported elsewhere. Just went with that approach in the end